# Reduction of Quadratic Form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm an exercise problem given in Mathematics for Physics.

---

Show that the matrix
$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
b& c
\end{bmatrix}$$
representing the quadratic form
$$Q(x,y)=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$$
may be reduced to
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0& 1
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0& -1
\end{bmatrix},\ \text{or}\ \ \begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
depending on whether the discriminant, $ac-b^2$, is respectively greater than zero, less than zero, or equal to zero.

---

As far I can understand, We have to write the matrix $Q$ in the diagonal form. To do so, WE have to find eigenvalues
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a-\lambda & b\\
b& c-\lambda 
\end{vmatrix}=0\rightarrow (a-\lambda)(c-\lambda)-b^2=0$$
$$\rightarrow \lambda^2-(a+c)\lambda+ac-b^2=0$$

$$\lambda =\frac{(a+c)\pm\sqrt{(a-c)^2+4b^2}}{2}$$
This doesn't seem to be working. Am I working in the right way? Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

Assuming $a\ne 0,c\ne 0$ and making $u = \sqrt ax, v = \sqrt b y$ we have

$$
P(u,v)=u^2+\frac{2b}{\sqrt{ac}}u v+v^2 = (u,v)\cdot M\cdot (u,v)'
$$

with $M = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \frac{b}{\sqrt{a c}} \\
 \frac{b}{\sqrt{a c}} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

but

$$
M = T^{-1}\cdot\Lambda\cdot T
$$

with $T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ \ \Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1-\frac{b}{\sqrt{a c}} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{b}{\sqrt{a c}}+1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

then

$$
(u,v)\cdot M\cdot (u,v)'=(u,v)\cdot T^{-1}\cdot\Lambda\cdot T\cdot (u,v)'\equiv(\xi,\eta)\cdot\Lambda\cdot(\xi,\eta)'
$$

and now regarding $\Lambda$ we can have $\{b=0, \frac{b}{\sqrt{a c}}=1, \{b\ne 0\cap \frac{b}{\sqrt{a c}}\ne 1\}\}$

Comment: I didn't get the correspondence between cases. You have divided things into three category $b=0,b=\sqrt{ac},b\not= \sqrt{ac}$ The first two  cases can reduce $\Lambda$ to first and third matrix.  What cases reduce this to the second matrix? Also given in the problem, $ac-b^2>0,=0,<0$. The equality case is second one in your cases. Other two inequality don't reduce $\Lambda $ any further.

Comment: Introduced a little correction.

Comment: In the problem that  is given! You mean

Comment: The corrections are active now. The previous attempt wasn't successful.

Comment: Your third case, I think just says that  $\frac{b}{\sqrt{ac}}\not = 1$ and $\not = 0$. Again, You can't reduce the expression $\pm \frac{b}{\sqrt{ac}}+1$ into anything.

Comment: The numbers $(1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon)$ can be scaled to $(1.-1)$ using  proportionality factors as follows: $(1+\epsilon)\lambda_1 = 1,(1-\epsilon)\lambda_2= -1)$ Those factors can be assumed in the $(u,v)$ definition: of course "a posteriori".

Comment: Got that Thanks!